# How to integrate 3rd party documents with sharepoint search

Tags: search, integration

I have document control system where I need to expose it's documents and document meta data to the Sharepoint 2010 search feature.

For example a user searches for widgets in Sharepoint and finds all the widget documents they have permissions for from the document control system.

I know nothing about Sharepoint, where can I find some information on integrating into it's search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Search supported Federated Searches. If your document control system supports Open search, the task is a lot easier. If not, then you'll need to build that connection. Federated Search is the way to go though (at least to start with).

Comment: Thanks, I built an open search web service and it worked.